# Is it possible to run PHP/JavaScript on an Android server?

Tags: javascript, php, android, apache

I've been tinkering to create an Android server now. Not an *actual* web server though; only one that would be accessible through WLAN connections to share files.

I've managed to build one using `Apache HTTP` libraries, thanks to this [wonderful guide](http://www.devlper.com/2010/12/a-bare-minimum-web-server-for-android-platform/). However, now I wanna set up the game a lil' bit by running some scripts.

The question is, is it possible to do so?

I've tried googling for clues but that one above was the best I could find.

Comment: If your server make response on http request, I thing it can be possible to make response as html page, where would be JS code. As I understand correctly your android server it is a simple Java web server, and you can work only with java files(not php)

Comment: Can you describe more about your idea and it dependence on PHP/JS

Comment: @OlegDokuka Well maybe a form validator or image gallery (many of 'em require JS or JQuery). Can I do that?

Comment: I`m not sure but I think it could be possible if we spent on it a few time. For make conclusion we should to know does this server can response us a simple html page, if it can give back text, we can try to put in it some html and see  how it would be rendered in browser if we call to server url

Comment: 'by running some scripts.'. What kind of scripts?